# PHP Regex to match everything between <body style=...> and </body> tag

Tags: php, html, regex, curl, match

I've got a cURL function that grabs everything on a specified page, but I only want the elements between the body tags.  I found this nifty regex to match everything between `<body>` and `</body>`, which worked.  But then I realized that one of the pages I need to use cURL on actually has a body tag with style info within it, so that what I actually want to match is everything *between* `<body style=...>` and `</body>`.  Does anyone know the regex expression to match that? Here's all of my code thus far...

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL); 
    ini_set("display_errors", "1");

    $pageToLoad = $_POST['load'];

        function get_data($url) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            $timeout = 5;
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $data;
        }

        $html = get_data($pageToLoad);
        $newHtml = preg_match("~<body[^>]*>(.*?)</body>~si", $html, $newHtml);
        print_r($newHtml);
?>
```

Comment: You should really use a HTML parser for this, as that's what they're built for.

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/

Comment: Great post @Quentin, mames me think that regexes would work for this case.  I espeically liked this quote: *It's considered good form to demand that regular expressions be considered verboten, totally off limits for processing HTML, **but I think that's just as wrongheaded as demanding every trivial HTML processing task be handled by a full-blown parsing engine**. It's more important to understand the tools, and their strengths and weaknesses, than it is to knuckle under to knee-jerk dogmatism.*

Comment: @user3121091 do you mean you *only* want elements that have a style attribute?  So <body style="...">sadsad</body> is good, but not to match <body>asdsa</body>?

Comment: @Daniel Gimenez--Exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be a dicey proposition trying to find a pattern in html when you're trying include attributes as part of your search pattern.  For example an attribute value can be single, or double quoted, and most parsers will be able to manage even if somebody forgot to quote something, or mismatched the quotes.  Since you're just looking for a specific attribute name, its easier, but there are still gotchas, such as if the attribute name you're looking for exists as a value in another attribute.

(Heck, your original simple regex would incorrectly match some improbable strings like `<bodycustomelement>...</body>`.

Since a style attribute is almost always followed by an equal sign, I will use that fact to find it.  I will also make sure I match a body element, and not some improbable mutant like the example above.

```
<body\s[^>]*style\s*=[^>]*>(.*?)</body>
```

### [REY](http://rey.gimenez.biz/s/6ka1s3)

This is essentially the same as your original regex but, with `\s[^>]*style\s*=` in the middle of it.

1. `\s` ensures that there is space after the body element so that it can only be a body element.
2. `[^>]*` matches any character but an `>` 0 or more times
3. `style` matches the string "style"
4. `\s*` allows for white space in between style and the equal sign
5. `=` matches the string "="

I'm hard pressed to think of an example that would befuddle this regex, that wouldn't also cause problems with a parser.  I suppose if somebody added white space between the `<` and `body` in the opening of the element, or they had space or any other characters in the closing of `body`.  Plus somebody might just omit the closing body element all together.

You can keep adding to the regex to handle the examples, but probably for any case you'll encounter in the wild, what I've given will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is using a regex like this one:

```
preg_match('|body[^>]*>(.*?)(?=\</body)|si',$html,$match); 

echo $match[1];
```

You want to use the S and I modifier for the Regex to span multiple lines and case insensitive.